# Problem receiving information / Exception has occurred TypeError

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

I want to read my information from the API. But facing this error.
[image]

This is the code I wrote:

```
import '../models/LocationListApi.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class Network {
  static Uri url = Uri.parse(
      "http://pelak.puladin.com/laravel-api/api/v1/places?category_id=11");

  static List<PlacesEntity> location = [];

  static void getData() async {
    location.clear();
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonDecode = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    var finalResponse = PlacesEntity.fromJson(jsonDecode['data']);

    for (var json in jsonDecode) {
      location.add(PlacesEntity.fromJson(json));
    }

    print(jsonDecode);
  }
}
```

The model I made to display information based on Jsonis as follows:
My model:

```
// ignore_for_file: file_names

class PlacesEntity {
  List<Place> places;

  PlacesEntity({
    required this.places,
  });

  factory PlacesEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PlacesEntity(
      places: List<Place>.from(json['places'].map((x) => Place.fromJson(x))),
    );
  }
}

class Place {
  int id;
  int pelak;
  String name;
  String intro;
  String description;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  String address;
  String phone;
  String email;
  String website;
  String instagram;
  String image;
  String category;
  String ads;
  String adsLink;

  Place({
    required this.id,
    required this.pelak,
    required this.name,
    required this.intro,
    required this.description,
    required this.latitude,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.address,
    required this.phone,
    required this.email,
    required this.website,
    required this.instagram,
    required this.image,
    required this.category,
    required this.ads,
    required this.adsLink,
  });

  factory Place.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Place(
      id: json['id'],
      pelak: json['pelak'],
      name: json['name'],
      intro: json['intro'],
      description: json['description'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      address: json['address'],
      phone: json['phone'],
      email: json['email'],
      website: json['website'],
      instagram: json['instagram'],
      image: json['image'],
      category: json['category'],
      ads: json['ads'],
      adsLink: json['ads_link'],
    );
  }
}

class MyJson {
  PlacesEntity data;
  int status;

  MyJson({
    required this.data,
    required this.status,
  });

  factory MyJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyJson(
      data: PlacesEntity.fromJson(json['data']),
      status: json['status'],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to make it into a list that I could read in the app, but I couldn't. The problem may be with my model. Anyway, this is a problem that has arisen for me. I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: share your JSON response. dose Response even contains a list value? if yes then you need to check with which key that list value is.

Comment: No, it has different types. Jason's list is easily visible from the link:
 [link](http://pelak.puladin.com/laravel-api/api/v1/places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApiClass{
  Future<List<Place>> fetchUsers()async{

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://pelak.puladin.com/laravel-api/api/v1/places?category_id=11"));

    List listData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["places"];

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var result = listData.map((e) => Place.fromJson(e)).toList();
      for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
        print(result[i].name);
      }
      return result;
    }else{
      throw Exception("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to access this. Create an instance of Network class and a late initialized List where you want to use it.

```
final Network networkObject = Network();
late List<Place> placeList;
```

Create a new async method and call it in initState:

```
void apiCall()async{
    placeList = await networkObject.getData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend
Please explain how to add to my list?
Because I receive different values from Jason and I want them to be added to the list or map

Comment: I tested it, but it does not show the output with a print!

Comment: its working for me.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRE6w.png

Comment: For me, in the result[0].name line, it gets an error from name and does not recognize it.
I also put the model code. Maybe there is a mistake in the model